# Can't save templates containing Query tags

Tags: templates, query

I've set up a staging server for an existing EE2 website, when I make changes to templates and save most templates save ok, but when I try to save a template that has an EE query tag, I get the following error and it fails to save:
'You don't have permission to access /system/index.php on this server.'

If I remove the query tag, it saves with no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check if mod_security is installed on your server and either disable it or change the configuration. My guess is that your issues is that mod_security is seeing the SQL query in your query tag and blocking the submission.

Comment: The host's support has offered to disable mod_security for his domain, is that advisable?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be fine.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Correction, it did work (the wrong domain was changed originally)